# What is the default padding between Leading widget and title widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that the default horizontal padding in **ListTile** is 16

If **contentPadding** is not used then the ListTile default horizontal padding is `EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0)` as mentioned in documentation of ListTile.

Out of Curiosity I want to know that what is the padding between (**Leading widget**) and (**Title and Subtitle widgets**)? and How do I change it?

Any help would be nice!

Comment: It seems I can't change the default padding between leading and title , So I am using Row

Answer (score 1):

You can check this in the code of [ListTile Widget](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/8874f21e79/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/list_tile.dart#L1289):

```
  // The horizontal gap between the titles and the leading/trailing widgets
  double get _horizontalTitleGap => 16.0 + visualDensity.horizontal * 2.0;
```

Which I believe is what you're looking for.

(As a side tip, if you have more curiosities like this you can always browse through the code yourself, even through your IDE.)

Comment: and how do I change it? @Nasalauksy